# Angular Dashboard Grid

Tags: angular, grid, dashboard, gridster

I've been spending my days trying to implement a dynamic dashboard grid with angular.
I tried Angular-Gridster, Gridstack, Packery and now i think I'll try Muuri

But none of them seem to fulfill all needs:

- Drag'n'Drop vertically & horizontally
- Responsive working (mobile, wrapping)
- Working angular wrapper
- Custom min-width/min-height of a component, independently from row/cols
- Good documentation

Has anyone of you managed to get something like this working smoothly?
What library have you been using, are you satisfied with how it turned out?